# How to add an Image URI to Listview

Tags: android, listview

I have created a student information app that will ask the user for their picture, lastname, firstname and their course. I already have the code to let the user upload their picture.

I want to get the image that I have uploaded and add it to my listview. Thanks

Here is my code:

AddStudentActivity.java

```
ListView listView;
    ImageView studentImage;
    EditText studLname, studFname;
    Button btnSave, btnCancel;
    Spinner cboCourse;
    String selectedCourse;
    Uri imageUri;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    StudentAdapter studentAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_student);

        //
        studentImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        studLname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        studFname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        cboCourse = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        btnCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncancel);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        cboCourse.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        studentImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this);


        studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter(this, studentArrayList);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Unsaved Changes");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("LEAVE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.imageView2:
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
                break;
            case R.id.btnsave:
                if(studLname.equals("") || studFname.equals("") || cboCourse.getSelectedItem().equals(0)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fields can not be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    //add a statement to add an item here
                    studentArrayList.add(studentImage.getResources().toString(), studLname.getText().toString(), studFname.getText().toString(), cboCourse.getSelectedItem());
                    listView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item successfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent home = new Intent(AddStudentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(home);
                    studentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.btncancel:
                studLname.setText("");
                studFname.setText("");
                cboCourse.setSelection(0);
                break;
        }
    }

    //handles opening the camera

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            studentImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //for the spinner
        int sid = parent.getId();

        switch (sid){
            case R.id.spinner:
                selectedCourse = this.cboCourse.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
ArrayList<Student> studentArrayList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    StudentAdapter studentAdapter;
    ListView listView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        studentAdapter = new StudentAdapter(this, studentArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);
    }


    //back button
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }else if(id == R.id.action_add){
            Intent add = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddStudentActivity.class);
            startActivity(add);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //show add menu

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Student.java

```
public class Student implements Serializable {

    private int image;
    private String lname, fname, course;

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
}
```

Comment: You should add the image in the **Student.java** model class and update the adapter to reflect on ListView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to add images to an Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020344/easy-way-to-add-images-to-an-android-listview)

Comment: Are you still dealing with _ListView_? Use must use _RecyclerView_

Comment: @Piyush This is an exercise given to us by our instructor and he told us to use listview.

Comment: For loading image in listview. Simply use Glide and load url in it

Comment: I'm really frustrated about this. This is my second post already and I think all of you have misunderstood my question. I know how to add an image to the listview since I have done it in the past, the issue here is that HOW TO ADD AN IMAGE URI that is why my code is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of library like Fresco, Glide etc that helps you to load images in list view. BTW why you are using listview now? I should say you need to use Recyclerview instead of LV.
Is there any particular reason to use Serializable? you can use android provided Percelable which is much more relevant.